# Uncaught TypeError: this.context.router.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-router

Just as the post is called that's what I get from the browser console.
Trying to change to a profile page after I click a dropdown button.
Code :

```
contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.func
},
_handleProfile: function(e){
    this.context.router.push("profile");
},


<NavDropdown eventKey={3} title={this.props.email} id="collapsible-nav-dropdown">
    <MenuItem eventKey={1}>
        <Button className="dropdown-button" onClick={this._handleProfile} bsSize="small">
            Profile
        </Button>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem divider />
    <MenuItem eventKey={2}>
        <Button  className="dropdown-button" onClick={this._handleLogout} bsSize="small">
            Logout
        </Button>
    </MenuItem>
</NavDropdown>


Using React.createClass,react-bootstrap,react-router
```

**Edit:** routes added.

```
var Router = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={app}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Index} />
        <Route name="login" path="login" handler={Login} />
        <Route name="profile" path="profile" handler={Profile} />
    </Route>
);
```

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using?  There's some significant changes between 1.x and 2.x.  Checkout https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md

Comment: 1.13 is my version of react-router checked with npm list react-router.

Comment: Hmm! The github page only has tags for 0.13.x and 1.0.x versions.  In any case you're probably using the 2.0 docs which is not your version. Take a look specifically at: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#navigating-in-route-components

Comment: as mjhm already figured out there is no version 1.13. I also encourage you to upgrade to react-router 1.0.3 (as there is no stable 2.x release yet) with history 1.17.0

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest react-router v4 the solution for this issue requires:

```
this.context.router.history.push('/path');
```

The new react-router v4 has changed the location of the push method when accessing this.context.router. router now has history and route as properties and it is within history that you will find the allocated method.

This might not be suitable for older versions as v4 had been a rewrite and is not backwards compatible. Due to this issue being the first one to come up in the a google search with the key words:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.context.router.push is not a function
```

and i had answered a similar issue on another thread i have decided to add the same explanation here in case any future developer might comes along here first.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16180999)

Comment: @stef: Improved formatting and upvoted because **NOT** link-only and internal link.

Comment: @help-info.de okay. I'd argue it doesn't answer the question and would be better as a comment.

Comment: @stef: agreed - after reading again. REVIEW will make the decision to delete.

Comment: I have edited the post to reflect your concerns. I hope this clears it up.